# Postman AssertionError: expected [ Array(9) ] to have property 'EID'

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, postman, assertion

Response body:

```
[
   {
      "fleets":[
         "efgh"
      ],
      "cellVersion":"FWA 1.2",
      "mainVersion":null,
      "deviceConfiguration":{
         "id":"af405fa16e25",
         "name":"Pal_testBed_1",
         "gps":{
            "position":30
         },
         "sensorsMap":[
            {
               "address":"29",
               "signalId":3
            },
            {
               "address":"29",
               "signalId":4
            }
         ],
         "protocol":"generic"
      },
      "simCard":{
         "id":"d0"
      },
      "status":"activated",
      "owner":"4f99",
      "name":"Test",
      "EID":"simulator3",
      "id":"5678"
   }
]
```

Postman testcase:

```
pm.test("Check if body has devices list", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("EID");
})
```

Error:

Check if body has devices list | AssertionError: expected [ Array(9) ] to have property 'EID'

Comment: Your JSON data is an array, you can check for your each element in this array. for first element you can use `pm.expect(jsonData[0]).to.have.property("EID");
})`

Comment: If want to check:
pm.expect(jsonData[0]).to.have.property("fleets","EID","gps","signalId");

Error:
Check if body has devices list and grab first device | AssertionError: gps: expected { Object (fleets, cellFirmwareVersion, ...) } to have property 'fleets' of 'EID', but got [ Array(14) ]

Comment: Can you post the raw code please, rather than an image of it? Makes it easier for people to run it locally in a mock etc.

Comment: [{"fleets": ["efgh"],"cellVersion": "FWA 1.2","mainVersion": null,"deviceConfiguration": {"id": "af405fa16e25","name": "Pal_testBed_1","gps": {"position": 30,},"sensorsMap": [{"address": "29","signalId": 3},{"address": "29","signalId": 4}],"protocol": "generic",},"simCard": {"id": "d0",},"status": "activated","owner": "4f99","name": "Test","EID": "simulator3","id": "5678"}]

Revoved one array to fit in the limit

Answer (score 0):

You *could* add something basic to loop through each `object` in the `array` to check for those properties:

```
pm.test("Check if body has devices list", function () {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (item) => {
        pm.expect(item).to.have.property("EID");
        pm.expect(item).to.have.property("fleets");
        pm.expect(item).to.have.property("gps");
        pm.expect(item).to.have.property("signalId");
    })
})
```

This is an example of how it can be checked but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to achieve the same thing.